# C++ ofstream delete and cleanup

Tags: c++, stl, standard-library, ofstream

I am writing a C++ ofstream that sometimes must be cleaned up - the file I am writing to should be deleted and the class deleted and cleaned up.

How?  (Except closing it and deleting it by name).

(At least the file should not exist with the intended location and filename with which it was opened - tempfile directory could be OK)

Comment: You cannot safely delete/move a file that is still open.

Comment: What I meant is that the file might have a temporary name until I close (It seems to be that way in my Visual C++ version).  If I can soemhow just leave it there, it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no other way.  Close the file and use
`remove` with its name.

This is probably best handled by some sort of RAII class;
I regularly use an `OutputFile` class, which converts implicitly
to `std::ostream&` (for output).  The constructor takes the name
of a file; there is a `commit` function which closes the file,
but if the destructor is called before `commit`, it not only
closes the file, but deletes it.   Similarly, there is an
`UpdateFile` class, which opens
`filename.new`—`commit` then renames
`filename` to `filename.bak`
(deleting any previously existing file with that name), and
moves `filename.new` to
`filename`.  And the destructor deletes
`filename.new`.  (A variant checks whether the
new contents are different from the old in `commit`, so that the
file timestamp won't change if there's no change in contents.)